# How to make sure elements of a concurrent list in java, that are added after the list has been looped through, are handled properly?

Tags: java, collections, java.util.concurrent

I have a concurrent list of objects. Multiple threads add to this list. At some point I loop through this list and perform operations on the list elements. How do I ensure that I process the elements that are added while looping through the list?

Main Thread:

```
List<Object> someList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Object>());
for(Object o : someList){
    o.toString();
}
```

Some other Thread:

```
getSomeList().add(new Object());
```

Note: I want to process the object after i start looping through the list (or after that).

Comment: Do you have code you can share? The answer would depend on exactly what sort of list you're talking about, how you loop through it, how new elements are added, etc.

Comment: Do you mean how to ensure that all the elements have been added *before* looping through the list?

Comment: I think the question is too vague for a good answer.  In situations like this, I'd probably define my own `class` to represent this list, probably with its own iterator or method to process the entire list, that would set some sort of flag when iteration starts and clear it when the iteration is done; then the `add` method would have to check this flag and maybe set up a separate "to-do" list of new items, and the iteration method would need to check this to make sure it processed those.  That's just one possible approach, but I think you'll need to do something like that.

Comment: Yes i am thinking of having my own class to implement this. I was wondering if there was some existing solution (in the concurrency library, Google guava etc) that i should be using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a synchronized java.util.List won't work since the iterator becomes invalid as soon as the source list is modified.  Sounds like you have a producer-consumer problem.  You should look into a Queue.  Try java.util.Concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue if you want an unbounded queue or java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue if you want a blocking queue.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be able to add elements in thread A while thread B is looping through the list is for thread B make a copy of the list as it is at that exact point in time, then getting an `Iterator` or `Enumerator` from it. If you don't make a copy before looping, then you'll get a `ConcurrentModificationException` if another thread adds an element while the other thread is looping.

Comment: This answer is describing the behaviour of certain specific list implementations provided by the Java library. One could implement their own data structure that would handle the scenario differently.